# How to register Outlook 2011 to send emails from iPhoto?

Tags: photos.app, ms-office

I had Office 2008 for Mac (with Entourage) installed. I never used Entourage and didn't have any email accounts configured. Then I installed Office 2011 without 'uninstalling' 2008 and setup Outlook 2011.

However in iPhoto I only see Mail and Entourage as the options for sending mail.

Any ideas how I can get Outlook 2011 to come up in the Entourage Mail options?

I am running Snow Leopard and iPhoto that came with my late 2009 MBP.

Thanks,
Sumit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this, but some poking around turned up [this article](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20026898-263.html), which basically involves modifying the Entourage script to use Outlook instead. The instructions are for iPhoto '09, but the comments indicate that it should work with iPhoto '11.

Comment: Fantastic pointer. Thanks. I followed the steps in the above article and was able to successfully connect iPhoto ('09) to send mails via Outlook 11.